# Can't access a route on deployed link, Next 13.4

Tags: next.js, router, next.js13

So i just made an airbnb clone using the latest version of nextJs(13.4.12). When i navigate to a certain page, instead of navigation to that page, i get the following params set in the uri instead.

https://vacation-zeta.vercel.app/?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fvacation-zeta.vercel.app%2Freservations

it should be
https://vacation-zeta.vercel.app/reservations
instead but this is not working in deployed links. Although its working in development mode.

Anyone knows the fix to this?

I have no idea where the error is originating from, might be router.push()?